# How to write an efficient LINQ query for a self-referential many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many, self-reference

I have the following model, representing a self-referential many-to-many relationship between Person and "Assistant" (which is just another Person):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Assistants { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> AssistantTo { get; set; 
}
```

But I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around  how to query for a *specific* assistant **efficiently** with LINQ.  I know I can do something like this:

```
    public Person GetAssistant(int assistedPersonId, int assistantId)
    {
        var assistedPerson = _context.People.Where(p => p.Id == assistedPersonId)
            .Include(a => a.Assistants)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return assistedPerson.Assistants.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == assistantId);
    }
```

How would I achieve that with one LINQ call?  In pseudo-code, I'm looking for something like:

```
    public Person GetAssistant(int assistedPersonId, int assistantId)
    {
        return = _context.People.Where(
            PERSONID == assistedPersonId AND 
                        PERSON HAS AN ASSISTANT WITH assistantId)
        ;
    }
```

Comment: From your first snippet, you're simply returning the assistant, correct? Then why not simply query `_context.People.Where(p => p.Id == assistantId)`. The assistedPersonId doesn't really matter, since you're wanting the assistant. You could use it as a sanity check (is the assistant really an assistant to assistedPerson?) - but that's separate from loading the person.

Comment: You're right, but yes, i think I'm using it as a sanity check.  Think of it as something initiated from UI, when viewing a Person's Details page. I want to list all assistants that the person may have, and then I may want to click on a particular assistant to view mode details.  The sanity check would ensure to pull up an assistant ONLY if that person is indeed an assistant to the specific person.  Ugh... convoluted language, hope this makes sense. :-)

Comment: In that case I'd write something like `_context.People.Where(p => p.Id == assistantId && p.AssistantTo.Any(pa => pa.AssistedPersonId == assistedPersonId))`

Comment: That worked. Too often the answer is simpler than I think. :-)  If you add this as an answer (rather than comment), I'd be more than happy to mark it as official "answer." Thanks either way.

Comment: No worries mate, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an assistant is also a person, we can load it directly without having to get it via the `AssistantTo` row.

The query simply becomes:

```
_context.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == assistantId);
```

However, since we're also including business logic (that we want to make sure this assistant is actually an assistant to the correct person) - we can restrict the query:

```
_context.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == assistantId && 
                        p.AssistantTo.Any(pa => pa.Id == assistedPersonId));
```

Comment: Thanks. Small correction.  Since `AssistantTo` contains a collection of Person entities, it would be this actually: `p.AssistantTo.Any(pa => pa.Id == assistedPersonId)`.